# Prometheus for k8s - "Context Deadline" as soon as a worker node is added

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to deploy Prometheus using the following [link](https://www.metricfire.com/blog/how-to-deploy-prometheus-on-kubernetes/).

When I try running it on a single-node K8S cluster setup, it runs completely fine.

[image]

http://< master-node-host-ip >/targets

[image]

However, when I add a Worker Node to the k8s cluster and try to delete the pod and create a new pod on a worker-node, somehow the Prometheus doesn't work.

Output:

[image]

Link:

http:< worker-node-IP >/targets
[image]

Here is my Configuration:

[image]

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t9SD.png):

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your issue is in the targets. At least you should verify this.

Right now you scrape only from  `localhost:9090`. But what about `http:< worker-node-IP >` ?

from [Querying multi-target exporters with Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/multi-target-exporter/#querying-multi-target-exporters-with-prometheus):

> we add the actual targets under static configs: targets. We also use
> several because we can do that now:

```
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - http://prometheus.io    # Target to probe with http
      - https://prometheus.io   # Target to probe with https
      - http://example.com:8080 # Target to probe with http on port 8080
```

Your version is

```
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - localhost:9090
      - worker-node-IP:9090
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I tried updating the config and it still isn't working.

Comment: Updated the config in the question as you suggested